# Where are stored sources of compiled programs?

Tags: compiling, source, source-code

I want to find exact source code of compiled program in Linux/Unix systems.

*for illustration:*

```
computer:/ username$ whereis ping
/sbin/ping
```

And the task is to find the source code of **/sbin/ping**.

Comment: Which Linux distribution?

Comment: The sources of a compiled program is not necessarily _anywhere_ on your computer. What Linux distribution are you using, or more importantly, what package manager are you using to install software?

Comment: @muru I rather want where can I find these informations for different distros.

Comment: @Kusalananda Is package manager important if I'm talking about system command (ping)? I assume it should be on github. Let's say FreeBSD.

Comment: Well, start from the distro's website then. Voting to close as too broad

Comment: @muru I think your comment was useful for me. I was searching for something but can't figure out where to go. Now I know it depends on distro and it doesn't have as similar rules.

Comment: A package manager can sometimes be used to retrieve source code packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code of a compiled binary may not be available on your system.

---

On [OpenBSD](https://www.openbsd.org/) (which is not Linux), the source code is for the complete base system (including kernel and utilities like `ping`) is available over CVS.

For a web-browsable OpenBSD repository, see https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/

The `ping` sources is located in [`src/sbin/ping`](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/sbin/ping/).

---

The [NetBSD](http://www.netbsd.org/) project (again, not a Linux) has a browsable CVS repository at http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/

The source for `ping` is located in [`src/sbin/ping`](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/sbin/ping/) in that tree, as for OpenBSD.

---

The [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/) project (which is also not Linux) has a GitHub repository at https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd

The source code for `ping` is located at [`sbin/ping`](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/tree/master/sbin/ping) in that tree.

---

On these BSD system, the source of the base utilities and kernel will only be available on the system if a user has checked out the respective repositories.

(the Makefiles with the build instructions for) Third-party tool packages/ports are kept in a separate repository for all three of these operating systems, and the source code is usually fetched from the main distribution site of the tool in question if one decides to compile the tool oneself and not use a ready-made binary package/port.

See the documentation provided by the relevant Unix for how to go about using their package/port system.

---

For Linux utility source code, you would have to first figure out what package the utility comes from, and then (if possible) use the package manager software to fetch the source code for the package. Alternatively, find where the source code is fetch from by the package maintainers when they create a binary package.  This would be different depending on what Linux and package manager software you are using.

Comment: For example, in Debian you can enable the `deb-src` entries in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and pull the source with `apt-get source packagename`